# Why is the input text in Firefox microscopic?

Tags: html, forms, firefox, google-custom-search

I am working on a [site](http://dev.rouviere.com) and have a Google CSE input that works fine, except the input field text does not display properly in Firefox. It looks fine in Chrome and Safari. But is absolutely microscopic in FF. The input field is in the upper right corner of the page.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="http://dev.rouviere.com/search-results/" id="cse-search-box">
  <div>
    <label for="q">search</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="017425724926122041548:nrhzbynfo9u" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:9" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" autocomplete="on" size="31" style="font-size: 13px; color:#797979;" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
form input#q { 
    height: 20px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important; 
    color: #797979; 
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Note on the inline styling. Because Google applies some styling and my css styling was not having effect, I added the inline styling as well.

Comment: This sounds stupid, but is your browser zoomed?

Comment: No questions are stupid, but no, it is not zoomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not rendering microscopic, it's being hidden by your padding/input height.

If you change the following rules it should work:

```
input#q {
  height: 25px !important;
  ...
}

form input {
  padding: 5px 2% !important;
  ...
}
```

Although I would suggest restructuring your css to avoid having to use !important everywhere and being more specific about what you're trying to select in your rules.